# Execute Gradle plugin on CLI without respective task in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am looking for the Gradle equivalent to the Maven `mvn plugin:goal` *with the plugin **not** being part of the build definition*.

I want to implement a script that I can run against any of our Gradle-based projects. It would execute a publicly available Gradle plugin thereby first resolving the plugin itself against the repositories.